# AADSTS16000: Session is invalid due to expiration or recent password change

Tags: wpf, azure-active-directory

Using this project: https://github.com/AzureADSamples/NativeClient-DotNet

After logging in and then logging out. Im now gettings this error message when starting the application:
AADSTS16000: Session is invalid due to expiration or recent password change.

It also seems like the tokenfile is not created when I do login.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you run the sample step-by-step, exactly like it is described in the linked page ?